# How to check whether an azure resource is available (Up/Down)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there any way to check if an azure resource say azure IoT hub or event hub is available or not. By available i mean whether it is down / working / ok/up ? I am a fresher in Azure,if someone can show some light will be greatful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For listing availability statuses per resource group, you could try out the [Availability Statuses REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resourcehealth/availabilitystatuses/listbyresourcegroup). This would give you the availability information per resource in the resource group including a quick summary, that looks like this:

[image: Availability Statuses REST API Response]

***Additional Info:***

If you're looking for availability per resource type, you could try the Service Health tile on the Dashboard in the Azure Portal:

[image: Availability Status per Resource Type]

And even personalize your filters, and pin the filtered world map back to the Dashboard:

[image: Service Health Tile on Azure Portal Dashboard]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The status page on the Azure Website list the services health for all regions:
https://status.azure.com/en-us/status

I'd suggest that you also follow @AzureSupport on Twitter.

Comment: Can we provide an option to monitor or send alert the status of resources like iot hub/event hub to user.

Comment: Would https://status.dev.azure.com/_rss be useful in this case?  We use the RSS feed with Teams to get updates/alerts, which isn't the same as say an EventHub, but enough for most people.

Comment: User want to see the status of each resource under a resource gropu in a single page.Alert is not sufficient for them

Comment: Simply parse the info from the RSS feed and display it in your page.

Comment: I have created a class library which will check the URL availability for a webapi . Like if we get 200 response from url i will mark it as available else not available. Appservice is one of the resource in my portal. Do we have anything similar to this to show the availability check?